# Problems to scan many images folders

Tags: php, debugging

I have more than 10 sections/articles in a single pages and each section display 3 thumbs.

3 thumbs > linking > to 1 Images_Main

Images_Main = thumb1, thumb2, thumb3

Structure:

```
Images
  |_______ 1stSection
               |__________ Images_Main
                               |__________ img1
                               |__________ img2
                               |__________ img3


               |___________ Thumb
                               |__________ img1
                               |__________ img2
                               |__________ img3
```

So, I have wrote this little code, which is working fine for the first section but is not working. It does not show right thumbs &/or Images_Main for the rest of sections.

It keeps showing images from first folder, does not matter if I change: `$smallSecond_dir = 'images/small225x341/ ** 2nd / 3rd / 4thTheme/ **';`

Gets Images_Main:

```
         <h5>
         <?php
         $smallSecond_dir = 'images/small225x341/2ndTheme/';
         $scan = scandir($smallSecond_dir);
         echo '<img src="' . $small225x341_dir . $scan[2] . '" alt="image" />'; 

        ?>
        </h5>
```

Gets Thumbs:

```
<ul class="thumbs">
            <?php

           $thumbs75x75_dir = 'images/thumbs75x75/2ndTheme/';
           $scan = scandir($thumbs75x75_dir); 

           for ($i = 0; $i<count($scan); $i++) {

           if ($scan[$i] != '.' && $scan[$i] != '..') {
            if (strpos($scan[$i], '.jpg') !== false) {
            echo '
             <li>
             <a href="' . $smallSecond_dir . $scan[$i] . '">
             <img src="' . $dir . $scan[$i] . '" alt="' . $scan[$i] . '" />
             </a>
             </li>';
            }
           }
           }; 
           ?>
          </ul>
```

How can I scan each sections folder and show right thumb and right Images_Main?

Thanks

Comment: For one thing, you are using a variable in your echo statement that you did not initialize here.  Did you mean $smallSecond_dir?  Also, I'm not entirely sure why you need scandir and cannot just specify your directory structure, since you know how many images you have.

Comment: Just as a sidenote: skip the "hi" and "thanks", there's no need. Here you say thanks with an upvote. Regarding the question, what do think that code is supposed to do, line by line? What happens instead?

Comment: The $smallSecond_dir comes from top <h5>

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly?

Comment: @Saul: When I copy and paste the code for each section/article and changes $thumbs75x75_dir = 'images/thumbs75x75/ ** 2nd / 3rd/ 4thTheme ***/'; does not not read the folder and/or Images_Main. It makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long time ago I wrote for some needing this code ... maybe will help you

```
$subgalery = array();
function read_dir($dir){
    global $subgalery;       
        if(file_exists($dir)){
        $opened = opendir($dir);
        while (($file = readdir($opened)) !== false){
            if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..' && (is_dir($dir."/".$file))){
                $subgalery[$dir."/".$file] = $file;
                read_dir($dir."/".$file);
            }
        }
        closedir($opened);
}
```

returns array of all forlders inside folder

You can make it without global, just put it inside with array_merge and return ... it is old code